# Good non-browser WCAG 2 Checker/Validator

Tags: accessibility, validation, wcag

Im looking a application based WCAG 2 Checker/Validator. Right now Im using TotalValidator the free version. Looking to purchase the full version for more extensive usability. Are there any other non-web based WCAG 2.0 checkers out there that works well or better that I should know of before I go ahead and purchase TotalValidator?

Thanks! I appreciate your time.

Comment: Did you check [http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete](http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Tanaguru (tanaguru.org)

Server side tool, free/libre software (AGPL license). People say it's good for the reliability of its results and automation on a whole website. By now (may'13) works with AccessiWeb (equivalent to WCAG).

Disclaimer: I'm quite deeply involved in Tanaguru :)